# Excel only referencing cells within the sheet I'm writing formula

Tags: excel

[image: Formula Example]

I am trying to make a lookup array table so it returns all of the values matching the code in sheet 1 with sheet 2. So in this screenshot all of the cells that have 11573 in column A of Sheet 2. Sheet1!B14 is the only cell that gets highlighted when I click on the formula. Am i referencing the cells wrong?

Edit- This is the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 2'!C$3:C$7845,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B14=Sheet '2'!$A$3:$A$7845,ROW('Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845)-2,""),ROW()-2)),"")
```

Comment: Write the formula rather than using an image.

Comment: It will not highlight cells in any sheet other than the sheet in which the formula is located.

Comment: I notice `Sheet1` is written with no space and `Sheet 2` has one. Is this wanted?

Comment: You also have a `Sheet '2'` which should probably be `'Sheet 2'`

Answer (score 0):

The formula below, which we assume is  located at `C14`, is not returning the expected values from another worksheet:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sheet 2'!C$3:C$7845,
SMALL( IF( Sheet1!B14 = Sheet '2'!$A$3:$A$7845,
ROW( 'Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845 ) - 2, "" ), ROW() -2 ) ), "" )
```

So let’s debug the formula:

1. *A worksheet name in the formula is inaccurate:* The formula was entered in the worksheet named `Sheet1` and it points to cells the worksheet named `Sheet 2` however the formula has `Sheet '2'`.
   When this formula is entered in the cell, it should have shown the `msoFileDialogOpen` `FileDialog` as Excel tries to open the file that contains the worksheet referred by the formula.

[image]

Apply the following adjustments to the formula: replace `Sheet '2'` with `'Sheet 2'`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sheet 2'!C$3:C$7845,
SMALL( IF( Sheet1!$E$14 = 'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845,
ROW( 'Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845 ) - 2, "" ), ROW() -2 ) ), "" )
```

2. However, the formula still not returning the expected results. Therefore, in order to debug the formula we need to change it in a way that it must retrieve all the values from range `'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845`, basically a criteria with no restrictions.

Replace `Sheet1!$E$14 = 'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845` with `'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 <> ""`.

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sheet 2'!C$3:C$7845,  
SMALL( IF( 'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 <> "",  
ROW( 'Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845 ) - 2, "" ), ROW() -2 ) ), "" )
```

[image]

3. Now we have a value returned by the formula, and it shows the problem. As the formula has no restriction it should have returned `Fld.03` instead returned `C14`, 11 rows below. That tells us that the inaccuracy is caused by this part `ROW() -2` which translates to “takes the row number of the cell where the formula is + 2” i.e. 10+2, so it’s taken the 12th Item instead of the first.

Replace `ROW() -2` with `ROWS( C$14:C14 )`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sheet 2'!C$3:C$7845,
SMALL( IF( 'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 <> "",
ROW( 'Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845 ) - 2, "" ), ROWS( C$14:C14 ) ) ), "" )
```

4. Now let’s bring back the original criteria.

Replace `'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 <> ""` with `'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 = Sheet1!B14`

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sheet 2'!C$3:C$7845,
SMALL( IF( 'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 = Sheet1!B14,
ROW( 'Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845 ) - 2, "" ), ROWS( C$14:C14 ) ) ), "" )
```

[image]

This formula can also be written as a *“standard”* formula using the [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) function:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( 'Sheet 2'!$C$3:$C$7845,
AGGREGATE( 15, 6, ROW(F:F) /
( 'Sheet 2'!$A$3:$A$7845 = $B$14 ), ROWS( F$14:F14 ) ), ROW(F:F) ), "" )
```

[image]